# Reversing a string in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift4.2

iOS 11, Swift 4.2, Xcode 10

Looking at SO and indeed googling all seem to suggest this should work, but it doesn't.

```
let str = self.label!.text
let newStr = String(str?.reversed())
```

I get an error message Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(ReversedCollection?)... so how do I get my string back?

Comment: You need to unwrap `str`.

Answer (score 13):

You should unwrap the `str` variable before set newStr:

```
guard let unwrappedStr = str else { return }
let newStr = String(unwrappedStr.reversed())
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't create String from optional ReversedCollection. You need to unwrap `str`.

```
if let str = self.label?.text {
    let newStr = String(str.reversed())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func reversed() -> String? {
        guard let str = self else { return nil }
        return String(str.reversed())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
str?.reversed()
```

Comment: Not sure that changing from method to property is a good idea, @linusgeffarth. If this is supposed to be a counterpart of the normal .reversed() then it should also be a method. IMO. :)

Comment: Counterpart or not, you can save those parenthesis. That's two chars less! :) Plus, I believe this better matches the Swift conventions. If you have followed the changes between Swift versions, you've noticed that they've changed a lot of functions to properties. Stuff like `.uppercased()` and similar, will likely follow.

Comment: For the sake of best answering (and matching) this question, I'll change it back to being a method, even though it was more sugar-y to my eyes before...

Comment: @LinusGeffarth You're right about the Swift changes. My intention here was only to keep some consistency. Thank you for editing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of variations on a theme here so far, so you know the basic issue – `str` is optional. We'll add a couple more (guard & map free ;-))...

For those who dream in C:

```
let newStr = str == nil ? nil : String(str!.reversed())
```

If you're not expecting `nil` and/or want a `String` back regardless you could use:

```
let newStr = String((str ?? "").reversed())
```

which is probably about as short as you can go.

Answer (score 1):

**Reverse a text value**
**You can pass a textfield value to another textfield by reversing**

***First View controller***

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var str = NSString()


@IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {


    let story: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let new = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RevViewController")as! RevViewController


    let str = txt1.text!
    new.txtvalue = String(str.reversed())


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(new, animated: true)


    }

   }
```

**Second view controller**

```
   class RevViewController: UIViewController {

 var txtvalue = String()

@IBOutlet weak var textfld2: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textfld2.text = txtvalue

}


}
```